# Codeforces 427B: Prison Transfer

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm sure that among you *(users of codereview)* there are many who are interested in [Codeforces](http://codeforces.com/) problemset. I tried to solve [427B: Prison Transfer tasks](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/427/B) but have `Wrong Answer` judjment at 4th test.

Maybe you've already solve the problem or is interested in solving? Can you find error in my code please?

*PrisonTransfer.java*

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class PrisonTransfer {

    protected static class FastScanner {
        BufferedReader br;
        StringTokenizer st;

        FastScanner(InputStream f) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));
        }

        String next() throws IOException {
            while (st == null || !st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            }
            return st.nextToken();
        }

        int nextInt() throws IOException {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        calcTransferCombinations();
    }


    protected static void calcTransferCombinations() throws IOException {
        FastScanner in = new FastScanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

        final int PRISONERS_NUMBER = in.nextInt();
        final int MAX_AGGRESSION = in.nextInt();
        final int RANK_LENGTH = in.nextInt();

        int combinations = PRISONERS_NUMBER - RANK_LENGTH + 1;
        int distanceToLastDangerous = RANK_LENGTH;
        int itr = 1;
        while (itr <= PRISONERS_NUMBER) {
            int aggression = in.nextInt();
            if (aggression > MAX_AGGRESSION) {
                if (PRISONERS_NUMBER - itr < RANK_LENGTH) {
                    combinations -= Math.min(PRISONERS_NUMBER - itr + 1, distanceToLastDangerous);
                    break;
                }

                int left = min(itr, RANK_LENGTH, distanceToLastDangerous);
                combinations -= left;
                distanceToLastDangerous = 0;
            }
            distanceToLastDangerous++;
            itr++;
        }

        out.print(combinations);
        out.flush();
    }

    protected static int min(int a, int b, int c) {
        int min1 = Math.min(a, b);
        return Math.min(min1, c);
    }
}
```

*PrisonTransferTest.java [all my tests complete succesfully]*

```
import mockit.Mock;
import mockit.MockUp;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

public class PrisonTransferTest {

    private static class FastScannerMockUp extends MockUp<PrisonTransfer.FastScanner> {
        private int[] input0 = new int[] {17, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1};
        private int[] input1 = new int[] {5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3};
        private int[] input2 = new int[] {8, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1};
        private int[] input3 = new int[] {4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1};
        private int[] input4 = new int[] {1, 1, 1, 2};
        private int[] input5 = new int[] {11, 4, 2, 2, 2, 0, 7, 3, 2, 2, 4, 9, 1, 4};
        private int[][] inputs = new int[][] {input0, input1, input2, input3, input4, input5};

        private int currInput = 0;
        private int pointer = 0;

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Mock
        int nextInt() throws IOException {
            return inputs[currInput][pointer++];
        }

        void switchInput() {
            currInput++;
            pointer = 0;
        }

        int getCurrInput() {
            return currInput;
        }

        int getInputsAmount() {
            return inputs.length;
        }
    }

    private static class PrintWriterMockUp extends MockUp<PrintWriter> {
        private int[] expectedResults = new int[] {9, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6};
        private final FastScannerMockUp scannerMockUp;

        public PrintWriterMockUp(FastScannerMockUp scannerMockUp) {
            this.scannerMockUp = scannerMockUp;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Mock
        public void print(int i) {
            System.out.println("Print input#" + scannerMockUp.getCurrInput());
            assertEquals(expectedResults[scannerMockUp.getCurrInput()], i);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Mock
        public void flush() {
            scannerMockUp.switchInput();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void calcTransferCombinations_test() throws IOException {
        FastScannerMockUp scannerMockUp = new FastScannerMockUp();
        PrintWriterMockUp writerMockUp = new PrintWriterMockUp(scannerMockUp);
        for (int i = 0; i < scannerMockUp.getInputsAmount(); i++) {
            PrisonTransfer.calcTransferCombinations();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the input and expected output on the 4th test?

Comment: We can review your code, but we're not exactly here to change what your code does. Code Review is primarily about making the code do the same thing (i.e. produce the same input/output) but in a different way.

Comment: There's a [post on the meta site](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1859/23788) about *technically off-topic but still reviewable code*, you might want to chip in ;)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Codeforces doesn't provide you with input of tests.

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk I'd suggest you either try to add more tests in your code, think of the *edge-cases* Try extremely small and extremely large inputs. Think for yourself what the results should be and check what your code produces. If this doesn't help you find the problem, change your approach drastically. There's something about `combinations -= Math.min(PRISONERS_NUMBER - itr + 1, distanceToLastDangerous);` that just feels strange to me. Although I haven't tried to understand that part of your code a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't help you with the wrong result your code produce, but I would strongly recommend separating the input/output logic from the computational logic.

Your current method is defined as:

```
protected static void calcTransferCombinations() throws IOException {
```

When I look at this method I wonder: Why do you need to throw an IOException to do some mathematics?

The answer is that you *read* from input and print to output inside the method. I don't recommend that.

Instead I recommend:

```
protected static int calcTransferCombinations(int numPrisoners, int maxCrime, int consecutiveCount) {
    ... calculate combinations ...
    return combinations;
}
```

That is, extract the input/output from that method. [Separation of concerns!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) A method should only do "one thing".

Also another note: Your current variables are named as constants, while being local variables. Only `static final` variables should be named `LIKE_THIS`. Other variables should be named `likeThis`.

Comment: In general, I am with you. In this case of a purely sequential O(1) spacewise task I don't see the need of separation. Correct me if I am wrong - do you propose to read in everything and then start processing?

Comment: @vnp No need to read in *everything* before processing. You could read one thing, process it, output it, read the next, process it, output it, etc.